# Inserting an existing value from column, to a true statement (if else) IN R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a df looking like this:

> | Speak_Dur|CNC_count|TNT_count|...
> |0.5       | 1       | 0
> |0.8       |  0      | 1
> |4.3       |        | 1
> |5.5       | 1       | 0

I want to make a few new columns using if else.
for the example, let's say I got only those 3 columns.
So I want to make a new column for each "X_count" variable I already have based on this condition:
new column "CNC_dur"= if cnc_count=1, then paste the "speak_dur" value from the same row.
new column "TNT_dur" = if tnt_count=1, then paste the "speak_dur" value from the same row.

results should be:

> | Speak_Dur|CNC_count|TNT_count|CNC_dur|TNT_dur|
> |0.5       | 1       | 0       |0.5    |0      |
> |0.8       | 0       | 1       | 0     | 0.8
> |4.3       | 0       | 1       | 0     | 4.3
> |5.5       | 1       | 0       |5.5    | 0

for now, I tried:

```
mutate(

CNC_DUR = if_else(CNC_count[row_number() -1] =="1","speak_dur",0,0))
```

I guess the last line should be something else,
hoping to get any help, thank you.

Comment: Personally, I like `case_when` over `ifelse` as it is easier to implement multiple conditions. It is a nice thing [to look into](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/case-when-r/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~"Speak_Dur", ~"CNC_count", ~"TNT_count",
0.5, 1, 0,
0.8, 0, 1,
4.3, NA, 1,
5.5, 1, 0)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(CNC_dur = ifelse(CNC_count == 1, Speak_Dur, 0),
         TNT_Dur = ifelse(TNT_count == 1, Speak_Dur, 0))
df2
#> A tibble: 4 x 5
#>  Speak_Dur CNC_count TNT_count CNC_dur TNT_Dur
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>1       0.5         1         0     0.5     0  
#>2       0.8         0         1     0       0.8
#>3       4.3        NA         1    NA       4.3
#>4       5.5         1         0     5.5     0
```

Then, if you want to write the file using the pipe delimiter:

```
write.table(x = df2, file = "file_with_new_columns.txt", sep = "|", row.names = FALSE)
```